# How do I fix my program that executes all the if statements, instead of executing them conditionally?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm really new to programming, so please excuse the inexperience. I've been playing around with JavaScript and I wrote this little tip calculator program:

```js
var bill = window.prompt("What did your bill come out to?");
var service = window.prompt("Was your service great, good, average, or bad?");

if ((service = "great")) {
  let total = bill * 1.2;
  console.log(total);
}

if ((service = "good")) {
  let total = bill * 1.1;
  console.log(total);
}

if ((service = "average")) {
  let total = bill * 1.05;
  console.log(total);
}

if ((service = "bad")) {
  console.log("Write a scathing online review! No tip!");
}
```

I got it to kind of work a little while ago, but there's a glaring bug. Instead of checking to see which if the statement is true and executing *only* that code, the program just executes all the code within all the statements regardless of user input.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you are using assignment `=` operator instead of equal `==` operator, change it to  `if (service == 'great'){`

Comment: Use `==` to compare values instead of `=` in your conditional which is assigning the value to `service` each time it's evaluated

Comment: Why can't you use switch case instead of if else

Comment: And consider making the value of `service` all lowercase before you do your `if`s or `case` blocks. Trimming it would be ideal as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using the assignment operator (=) instead of the comparative operator (==). So basically, every time the condition is checked, the service variable is assigned the latest value.
I have modified your code and added it below.

```js
var service = window.prompt("Was your service great, good, average, or bad?");

if (service === 'great'){
  let total = bill * (1.2)
  console.log(total)
  };

if (service === 'good'){
  let total = bill * (1.1)
  console.log(total)
  };

if (service === 'average'){
  let total = bill * (1.05)
  console.log(total)
  };

if (service === 'bad'){
  console.log("Write a scathing online review! No tip!")
 };
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for assignment. Using that in your conditional makes all the conditions true.

What you need is the `==` comparison operator (or `===`, that checks for both equal value and equal type). I also suggest, if only one condition can be met, to use `else if`.

```
if (service == 'great'){
  let total = bill * (1.2)
  console.log(total)
}
else if (service == 'good'){
  let total = bill * (1.1)
  console.log(total)
};
```

Alternatively, if you have to check a variable for many values, you can use the `switch` statement:

```
switch(service)
{
  case 'great':
  {
    let total = bill * (1.2);
    console.log(total);
    break;
  }

  case  'good':
  {
    let total = bill * (1.1);
    console.log(total);
    break;
  }

  case 'average':
  {
    let total = bill * (1.05);
    console.log(total);
    break;
  }

  case 'bad':
  {
    console.log("Write a scathing online review! No tip!");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it, thank you! I didn't know about switch before, thanks for showing it to me!